# Error response from daemon: network myapp not found

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a container in a multihost network but while creating I am getting this error:

```
Error response from daemon: network myapp not found
```

Here `myapp` is the name of overlay network which i have created. The command I am using is:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it --name=test_cont --net=myapp ubuntu bash
```

Comment: Does the network definitely exist? `docker network ls`

Comment: yeah i have checked it. Network is there.

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker network inspect myapp`?

Comment: Output of sudo docker network inspect myapp is here: http://postimg.org/image/wi4yx73hn/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker networks are scoped for different access. Your `myapp` network is an overlay network scoped to the swarm.

That means you can only use it at swarm level - `docker service create --network myapp` will work fine, because services are at swarm level too.

You can start a container with `docker run` on a swarm, but it will only run locally on the node where you run the command on, so it can't see swarm networks.

Comment: But i am not able to create any container. Basically i am implementing multi host server for that i have to create container.

Comment: In swarm mode you [create services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/deploy-service/) if you want to run containers across the nodes.

Comment: but we can create container on host with overlay driver which can communicate with other hosts container. Command for this is "docker run -itd --name=web --network=my-net --env="constraint:node==mhs-demo0" nginx"

Comment: Yes, but that container is not running in swarm mode - it will run on a node which meets the constraint, but if that node goes down your container won't be started on a different one, the swarm is not managing it. If you want swarm mode features, you need a swarm-scoped network and services. If you run `docker network inspect my-net` you'll see it's not scoped to the swarm.

Comment: command to create network in new version will be `docker network create  myapp`

Answer (score 132):

If you use `docker-compose` a less destructive option compared to prune is to force the recreation of your containers with:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: While I don't doubt that @bohendo is correct and that also fixes this issue, I found this worked for me. Personally I prefer logical fixes over flicking switches.. but that's me.

Comment: Thank! You save my day - I give you an awards: 

Comment: A system update seems to have corrupted the existing docker networks. I recreated all of them, but the containers still have reference to the previous instance of a specific network. This solved that problem - thanks!

Answer (score 35):

I started getting this error after doing a `docker system prune`.

`docker network ls` showed my network:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
pgl0gb0mbwql        myapp               overlay             swarm
```

But deploying the stack would give error like:

```
failed to create service myapp_database: Error response from daemon: network myapp not found
```

Then I asked myself the most important debugging question there is: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

I restarted my docker daemon and the network was deleted for real. I was then able to re-create it and everything started working again.

Comment: Well, thanks for posting that, because, lol, I had the same exact problem (lingering zombie overlay network) and restarting the docker service did the trick.  FWIW there's an [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39225) over on the Moby project that may be related (my zombie network appeared after a `docker swarm leave --force` command.)

Comment: That solved the problem for me. THANKS!

Comment: omg saved my day,  sudo reboot now  helped

Answer (score 27):

in my case i had to:

```
docker system prune
systemctl restart docker.service
```

to make it work again...

Comment: be careful this would erase everything

Answer (score 8):

Remove container (not Image) and then run again:

```
docker compose up
```

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally deleted the network bridge of my containers
and In my case i just need to do

```
docker compose -f "docker-compose.yaml" down
```

and then rebuild again and it worked

```
docker compose -f "docker-compose.yaml" up -d --build
```

PS: Unfortunately when you down the containers the database can be erase it if there is not mounted in a volume so watch out ^^

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it did not delete the network even though it was in swarm mode, but if I created it again, it threw an error because there was already a network with that name. I had to restart the docker service, these were the steps:

```
docker network rm myapp                   #launch the error that the network did not exist
sudo systemctl restart docker.service     #restart the docker service
docker network ls                         # not shows network.
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you connect myapp_net network to app_container then:

1. docker network disconnect -f myapp_net app_container # Force disconnect
2. docker network create myapp_net # Create docker network again
3. docker network connect myapp_net app_container # Connect docker network again

It could resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I ever wasn't need this network at all. It was a part of previous docker-compose config, not yet cleaned up.

```
docker-compose up --remove-orphans
```

helped me, since the mixed state with that network was removed, only then the new state that requires no network has started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was because of naming issue, recheck your network name in docker and give the same in your command.

steps I followed: (for windows)

1. stop all the docker service

> docker compose down

2. close docker GUI and restart the docker

> go to taskbar and click on show hidden icons --> right click it --> docker restart.

3. open terminal and go to the directory where the docker file is present (.yml)
4. run all the docker services using the cmd :

> docker compose up

5. open new terminal and run :
   check the network name

> docker network ls

6. copy the name and paste it in your network name section in your command.

> docker run --tty --network < here your network name > confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka: -C -s key=s -s value=avro -r http://schema-reg: -t postgres.public.shipments

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create this network:

```
sudo docker network create myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

For **docker-compose** users:

Check if that network is not *external*.

```yaml
networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
    external: true  # <--- means that the network has to be created.
```