# I am trying to create containers on docker host without swarm mode.I am getting error " Error response from daemon: network myapp not found"

Tags: docker

Command I am using `sudo docker run -itd --name=web --network=myapp nginx`. I am on ubuntu server OS.

[image: docker network inspect]

[image: docker info]

Comment: You've already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640963/error-response-from-daemon-network-myapp-not-found/39654147#39654147). The answer is the same.

Comment: I want to implement multihost networking without swarm mode. With the help of external KV store.

Comment: Your host is in swarm mode.

Comment: I have tried creating a host not in swarm mode by " sudo docker-machine create  -d virtualbox  --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip mhl-consul):8500"  --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:0"  mhl-demo0". But still error is same.

Answer (score 1):

You were created an overlay network with Docker Engine swarm mode, which name is "myapp". However, overlay networks for a swarm are not available to containers started with `docker run` that don’t run as part of a swarm mode service.

If you want create a network for your local containers, you should consider to create a local bridge network with the following command:

```
$ docker network create --driver bridge myapp
```

You may need to read that [Understand Docker container networks document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) carefully, which explained the difference between bridge network and overlay network very well.

Comment: But the offcial docs are creating containers by "docker run -itd --name=web --network=my-net --env="constraint:node==mhs-demo0" nginx".